# How to deploy Azure Sentinel ARM template using Azure Blueprints?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-sentinel, azure-blueprints

I have gone through the [Azure Sentinel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/quickstart-onboard) documentation. How to deploy the Azure Sentinel ARM template with help of Azure Blueprints?

Comment: You can easy add ARM Template as Artifact while creating the Blueprint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/create-blueprint-portal#create-a-blueprint

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared the Sentinel ARM template by following this [Azure Sentinel All In One](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/tree/master/Tools/Sentinel-All-In-One) documentation.

Next, I have followed the below steps for deploying the Sentinel ARM template using Blueprint:

1. Created a blueprint by adding the above Sentinel ARM template as an Artifact.
2. Published a blueprint with the latest changes.
3. Assigned a blueprint by providing the values to the parameters.

For reference [Quickstart: Define and assign a blueprint in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/create-blueprint-portal)